# Spotify playlists API call Not returning all playlists

Tags: spotify

I've been using this api call with my own account and turns out it doesn't return all my playlists... i'm using limit = 50 and offset = 0, but some playlists just don't get returned on the items array on the response.

BTW i own less than 50 playlists

Any hints on what may be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have private playlists and not set your scope properly.

Here are a list with all the scopes: [Web API: Using Scopes](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/using-scopes/)

Comment: just to be sure i'm using playlist-read-private playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the playlist-read-private scope. Using this scope fixed my problem.